# SSIS: Use System::TaskName inside the dataflow

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis, business-intelligence

For more detailed logging, I want to retrieve the [System::TaskName]

Right now, when starting from the task that fails we go to 'script task', there I fetch [System::TaskName] and write that in the log. Logically this writes the current TaskName = 'Script task' instead of the failed task
[image]

Problem is the System::TaskName is only know inside the task, logical...
In fact I want to update a variable 'User::CurrentTaskName' from inside the dataflow, = from inside the task.

This would be easiest if I could use a 'Script Task' component inside a dataflow but I can't find that.
Probably I need a workaround.

Hope you guys understand approximately what I mean...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are just wanting to catch the error message, use a log provider and make sure the OnError event is checked. As you add more and more packages to production, you'll appreciate this centralized error logging mechanism that requires little to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to access the TaskName by adding the following inside a Script Component.

```
Private Function ReadVariable(ByVal varName As String) As Object
    Dim result As Object
    Try
        Dim vars As IDTSVariables100
        Me.VariableDispenser.LockForRead(varName)
        Me.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(vars)
        Try
            result = vars(varName).Value
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            vars.Unlock()
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

and then accessing the variable like so

```
ReadVariable("System::TaskName")
```

Comment: which type of "script component type" do i need to choose ? 
Source / Destination / Transformation ? and does it even matter ? 

and when i enter "edit script", where do i put the function in the code ? 
is it after " Public Overrides Sub" and before "End Class" ?

Answer (score 5):

From the looks of your data flow, it looks like you're trying to implement error logging.  I've had good luck using an event handler for this sort of thing in the past.  It has the added benefit of cleaning up your layout and making the maintenance of the package easier in the future as you don't need to maintain linkage from all of your tasks to the error handling.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I know, I am using error handling but this is a bad example in the above screenshot, an attempt to fetch the TaskName.

If you could give me an example of an error handling task that can get/display/pop-up the 'current TaskName' that would be more than awesome... Thx

Comment: One of the system variables exposed to the OnError error handler **is** `System::TaskName`.

Comment: @Edmund has the right of it.  Use System::TaskName.  That should contain the name of the task that fails when the handler is invoked.