# Handling logging of task name using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have created a SSIS package and have a list of tasks that run in a sequence container. I need to log the start and end of execution of a package. For e.g The xyz package has started. The xyz package has completed.

The log table that I am logging to has the following columns that is Message and methodname. I need to pass the message in this parameter and method name will contain the name of the task. However in the message, I would like to have the task name as well. As mentioned above, The XYz task has started.

I have about 20 tasks in my package. I know that an execute sql task would need to be created in postexecute and preexecute event of each task. What I  need to know is the best approach in feeding the task name in the message column. Do i need to create a variable for all the 20 tasks and hardcode the value. If I take this approach I would be need to create 40 variables as 20 for message task has started and 20 for task has ended.

stored procedure

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertLog] 
    @message varchar(max),
    @methodName varchar(50),
    @errorCode varchar(25) 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    insert into CoreAnalytics.dbo.logs ([TimeStamp],LogLevelId,[Message],UserName,MethodName,LineNumber,ModelId)
      values( GetDate(),3,@errorCode + ' ' + @message,'xxxxxx',@methodName,0,'xxxxxxxx')
END
```

Variable parameter mapping
[image]

Error 
[image]

Mapping as per suggestion
[image]

Comment: What is the scope of the TaskEnd and TaskStart variables?   All I can see is "CoreRefere...".   Is that the whole package, or the name of a task?

Comment: It's name of package

Comment: Please note that I am executing the task in postexecute and preexecute event . Has it got to do with not having access to those system variables

Comment: It may be that the system::taskname variable can only be used in the task scope.   Look at how it is used in the answer to this question:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123544/ssis-use-systemtaskname-inside-the-dataflow   Also, see here:    https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/98a9527f-b112-49ee-966e-93cc700f6001/getting-the-task-name-when-an-error-occurs-ssis-2012?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 0):

Use the system variable, `System::TaskName`

Comment: I am currently using it to pass as parameter to methodname column. However I am using this storedprocedure in other tasks to log exceptions. How do I use it also to log information

Comment: Use it during the construction of your `@Message` variable.

Comment: Sorry didnt get you. I created a User defined variable called hasStarted whcih contained value has started and tried concatenating that in the parameter variable mapping. I am getting an error that it cant find the variable in the collection. I was doing System::TaskName + User::hasStarted

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you are suggesting

Comment: I think in order to give an example, I will need more information about what you are trying to do.   Can you post a screenshot of what you tried, and the error?

Comment: Ah yeah, that is not the right place to combine the two variables.  Make a third variable called `User::Message` (or whatever you want to call it), and in the expression for its value, combine the two like you have tried to do in your screenshot.   Then in the parameter assignment, just use the `User::Message` variable.

Comment: I tried you suggestion. I created a variable User::hasStarted and assigned a value System::TaskName + " has started". But when i check the database i dont see the value of  System::TaskName. I see the string value as it is

Comment: Again, I would need to see screenshots to be able to see what went wrong.

Comment: I have updated the post. I see no value in the message column in the database

Comment: Is it because the value is blank

Comment: I can see the following error Error: The variable "System::TaskName" was not found in the Variables collection. The variable might not exist in the correct scope.

Comment: Error: Attempt to parse the expression "@[System::TaskName] + " has started"" failed and returned error code 0xC00470A6. The expression cannot be parsed. It might contain invalid elements or it might not be well-formed. There may also be an out-of-memory error.

Comment: If I evaluate the expression @[System::TaskName] + " has started" in the expression editor , it returns the correct value.